# How to handle request from multiple users in nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, server, request

I was developing a Nodejs app with some express, and my app was working well on localhost until I deploy it and start to realize a serious issue.

So what my app does is it will create a socket to another server, the user will then feed it some data, it then uses that data to login on the other server through the socket, fetch data, do some magic to the data and return the result to the user.

The issue is let's say one user is using the app, if another user feeds it some data and command, it will immediately boot the other user out to login with the new data and jump to process the newest command, because there is only one instance of the app on the server.

I'm really at a loss on how to handle it. It seems like I would need to assign a separate socket and app instance for each user, but I'm not sure where to start. Also how do I clear up such app instance after the user is done with the site, since I'm sure if not my server will be full very quickly.

Sorry if my question seems very basic but I'm really just a beginner at this.

Comment: There are some definite things to check in your backend code.... I would say to check your backend and see if you are accidentally logging in over the top of the user. What does your login code look like?

Comment: Could you share some of your code? it's hard to say without seeing it, but it sounds like you are storing some data in global scope of the app and it gets overwritten when another user comes in.

Comment: I figure that this is the case and the main problem with my backend code (the app which handles the user request is a global object), problem is I'm not sure how should I fix it. Make that app a non-global obj is for sure, but then how do I assign each app instance to an user, how do I recognize that user to send the correct result to them.

Comment: @Slyph what library are you using for sockets? If you are just using express routes then every time a user hit the route the code is run in essentially in completely separate instances so you don't have to use global vars.

Comment: For socket, I'm using sockjs.